# I use dense rank function to generate random rank to students. Please give me code to extract only top 5% of the students

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Select 
    Student_Name,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE(1,999999)) AS RBORV    
From
    Stu
```

From the above sql i need to extract only top 5% of ranks(in order).. What should I add in where clause to do so

Comment: `TOP (5) PERCENT /* Return the top 5 percent of the result set. */`. Link - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187043(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is not SQL Server code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very straightforward way:

```
Select TOP 5 PERCENT Student_Name, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE(1,999999)) AS RBORV
        From Stu
    Order by RBORV
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions.  Using the code you have provided:

```
select student_name
from (select Student_Name,
             row_number() over (order by dbms_random.VALUE(1,999999)) AS RBORV,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from Stu
     ) s
where row_number <= cnt * 0.05;
```

This will work in Oracle (which looks like the code you are using).  In SQL Server, you could write the equivalent code as:

```
select student_name
from (select Student_Name,
             row_number() over (order by newid()) AS RBORV,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from Stu
     ) s
where row_number <= cnt * 0.05;
```

Or, more simply, as:

```
select top 5 percent student_name
from stu
order by newid();
```